Incremental sync issues on cloudQuery
What i've done till
I've fetched data from hubspot to postgres using cloudquery by creating 2 config file and running the full-sync. The config files are as:
hubspot.yml
kind: source
spec:
  name: "hubspot"
  path: cloudquery/hubspot
  registry: cloudquery
  version: "v4.4.3"
  destinations: ["postgresql"]  
  tables: ["*"]
  spec:
    app_token: "my_access_token"
    pagination:
      page_size: 1000
      max_retries: 5
    table_options:
      hubspot_crm_contacts:
        associations: ['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']
      hubspot_crm_companies:
        associations: ['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']
      hubspot_crm_deals:
        associations: ['contacts', 'deals', 'notes', 'emails', 'tasks', 'meetings', 'calls', 'company']

postgres.yml
kind: destination
spec:
  name: "postgresql"
  path: "cloudquery/postgresql"
  registry: "cloudquery"
  version: "v8.5.1"
  write_mode: "overwrite-delete-stale"
  spec:
    connection_string: "postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/dbsync?sslmode=disable"

Then after that i don't want to fetch all data again so i run an incremental sync by adding this part in hubspot.yml file:
  backend_options:
    table_name: "cq_state_hubspot"
    connection: "@@plugins.postgresql.connection"

And the sync completed.
Problem:
After conducting incremental sync only updates should be implemented and remaining should be as it was no ? But what happened is data is missing. I checked on contact table as how many data have association before the count was ~25_000 but after the incremental sync it has decreased to ~16_000.
I'm not able to figure out why this is happening.
And how can i conduct an incremental sync without loosing previous data.
Thank you.
First i did full-sync and after data updates i tried doing incremental sync but other data is affected too.
